# Python: How do I dynamically alter methods of dict and list objects?

Tags: python, list, dynamic, methods, dictionary

Here is a mockup of what I want to do:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5]   # create a vanilla python list object
replacef (alist)      # replace __setitem__, extend,... with custom functions
alist[0]=2            # now the custom __setitem__ is called
```

This is for a DSL project where the syntax should be as close to normal python as possible, so subclassing list and making the user call something like alist = MyList(1,2,3,4,5) is not desirable. Also, because the DSL needs to coexist with other libraries, globally changing list and dict is not an option...

I have tried creating instancemethods and setting them directly on the object like alist.append = myFunc, but Python says those properties are read only. Changing the `__class__` attribute seems to be not permitted as well.

Is what I am trying to do even possible in Python?

**Update**: here are some findings on what is possible with a subclass of object:

Given:

```
class y(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
def f(self):
    print self
    print self.a
    print self.b
    print self.c

class x(object):
def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
def f(self):
    print "x.f()"

>>> objy = y(1,2,3)
>>> objx = x(4,5,6)
>>> objy.f()
  <__main__.y object at 0x02612650>
  1
  2
  3
>>> objx.f()
  x.f()
```

It is possible to change the class of objx on the fly like this:

```
>>> objx.__class__ = y
>>> objx.f()
<__main__.y object at 0x02612D90>
4
5
6
```

Also, one can dynamically add/change object methods on the fly, much like in javascript:

```
>>> def g(self,p):
       print self
       print p
>>> import new
>>> objy.g = new.instancemethod(g,objy,y)
>>> objy.g(42)
<__main__.y object at 0x02612650>
42
```

However, both approaches will fail with objects that are implemented in C like dict and list:

```
>>> def mypop(self):
        print "mypop"
        list.mypop(self)


>>> alist.pop = new.instancemethod(mypop,alist,list) 

AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'pop' is read-only

>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x.__class__ = mylist

TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

The suggested approach to use something like alist = replacef(alist) would not work here, because replacef could be called from a `__setattribute__` call like this:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
aDSLObject.items = alist #  __setattribute__ calls replacef on alist
alist[0] = ....
```

So while it indeed is possible to change object methods dynamically, it seems like it is not possible to alter the behaviour of objects implemented in C - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can do the "alist = MyList(1,2,3,4,5)" thing inside the `replaceref` function?

```
def replacef(l):
    return MyList(l) # Return instance of list subclass that has custom __setitem__

alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
alist = replaceref(alist)
```

This way user would still use the standard list syntax when defining a list but would get the new **setitem** after `replaceref` call.

Comment: +1: Sweet solution to a weird problem.  Slightly different constructor syntax (`MyList` vs. `[`) is not a barrier to acceptance, so why worry about it?  But this solves it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is indeed a weird problem I suppose:)
Ideally, the user of the DSL should not have to know about the underlying implementation. I like the approach though. Maybe there is a way to change what 'alist' is pointing to without direct assignment, like a 'pointer to a pointer' in C?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. The closest thing probably is changing contents of mutable variable, say list. 
BTW if you managed to augment list instances with new behavior without changing the class -- that would feel somewhat scary. If there's code that uses type() and isinstance() and such, it wouldn't notice the difference and would perhaps cause unintended side effects...

Comment: @__mme__: There's no reason to mess with "changing what `alist` is pointing to".  (A) it's impossible in Python.  (B) it's needless.  The DSL is the language, not the implementation.  As long as the syntax looks right, the implementation is nobodies business.  For an example, look at Python's `re` package.  The implementation is not called `re`, so the classes aren't exactly what you'd expect from the documentation.

Comment: @S.Lott: It would indeed be possible to change it with the 'inspect' package and the currentframe function, but this would be prone to all kinds of problems... I did not understand what you want to say about the syntax, but maybe I should make myself more clear: The code mockup I provided is what my problem with the DSL boils down to, not the actual syntax of the DSL itself. The idea of the DSL is to modify objects including dicts and lists that get passed to DSL functions to silently log their state changes and replicate them to another machine.

Answer (score 2):

"Explicit is better than implicit."  You should just document that your users need to use `MyList()` instead of `list()`.  You and your users will be happier in the long run.

Ruby allows what you want, by the way.  With Ruby, you can open up global objects and just add new behaviors.  I find this scary, and Ruby runs slower than Python, so I'm not actually urging you to switch to Ruby.

So, provide `MyList()`, and provide a way to take an existing list and wrap it in a `MyList()`.

You could write `MyList()` to just take a bunch of arguments, and make a list very conveniently:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.lst = args
    # add other methods to MyList() here
```

then you could call this with `MyList(1, 2, 3, 4)` and the instance would have a member called lst with the value: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

But now, if you want to make a `MyList` instance out of a list, how do you do that?  If you do this:

```
new_list = [1, 3, 5]
x = MyList(new_list)
```

then you have just set x to: `[[1, 3, 5]]`

So I recommend you make `MyList()` just take a list argument and save it:

```
def ensure_list(seq):
    try:
        seq[0]
        return seq
    except TypeError:
        return list(seq)

class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.lst = ensure_list(seq)
    # add other methods to MyList() here
```

I just edited this answer.  Originally, I had a call to `list()` where I now have put a call to `ensure_list()`.  `ensure_list()` checks to see if you can index its argument; if you can, it is either a list already or something that can act like a list, and it is returned unchanged.  If you can't index it, then `ensure_list()` calls `list(seq)` to try to turn it into a list.  This will work with iterators and generators, forcing them to expand out to a list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You do have a point that sometimes making things more explicit is easier to understand. I am thinking about the consequences of an explicit wrapper call for dicts and lists. However, I am still curious if what I am asking for is possible, given the numerous options Python provides to extend the syntax.

Comment: Python doesn't quite offer the ability to completely remap the syntax.  For example, it is easy to set up a class such that a member of the class is read-only, and any attempt to assign to the class member will fail and raise an exception; but it is impossible to make a simple variable behave the same way.  You could do something like `foo = dict(whatever); foo = do_magic(foo)`  And since `dict`s are mutable, you could go through all the entries and do something to them.  But there is no way to non-explicitly rebind a variable, so you can't change the type of an object on the sly.